# Does Particular Point Topology has Fixed Point Property?

Tags: general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

A [Particular Point Topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology) is not compact, is path-connected but what about Fixed Point Property? Does it have fixed point property? If so how?

I have been told that it should have Fixed Point Property. But I do not know how to Prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose that $X$ is given the particular point topology with particular point $p$, and let $f : X \to X$ be continuous.  If $f(p) = p$, we're done.  If $f(p) \neq p$, then $\{ f(p) \}$ is closed in $X$, and so $f^{-1} [ \{ f(p) \} ]$ is also closed in $X$.  What are the closed subsets of $X$ like?

Comment: why is V=X∖{f(p)} open?

Comment: Sorry, I changed my answer a bit.  (I exchanged open sets for closed sets, but otherwise kept the same structure.)  Note that $p$ is an element of $X \setminus \{ f(p) \}$ if $f(p) \neq p$, and is thus open according to the definition of the particular point topology.

Comment: The closed subsets of X does not have the particular point p.

Comment: @da_elysian_fields: There is _one_ closed set that you are forgetting about.  A _very_ important closed set for this problem.

Comment: do you mean empty set?

Comment: @da_elysian_fields: The empty set also does not contain the particular point.  But there is _one_ closed set which does contain it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11851/discussion-between-da-elysian-fields-and-arthur-fischer)